# Spring Session scope use for user login

Tags: spring, session, scope

I'am new to spring and hibernate.I used a POJO class for maintain a sessoin data.i put scope as a session. here

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class SessionInfo {
    private int userId;
    private String loggingUser;

// getter and setter methods

}
```

then my controller class set as a scope="request" and methods in that controller i can pass the sessionInfo class and set/get session data.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(Model model,SessionInfo session) {
        session.setLoggingUser("akudahewa@gmail.com");
        // set model attributes ....
        return "BusinessCategory/index";
    }
```

Thats how i maintaining a session data in my application. In this way every time i need to pass the sessionInfo class in every method where needed and check is there any user in the session object, Is is way correct or not. and also cant we use intercepter for this. If not what is the best way to maintain the session data in spring.

Comment: Are you using Spring Security for managing the logins to your application? If so, they already have an abstraction for reaching the user in session.

Comment: Thax Ryan, I have used spring security for login. How can store the session details of logged in user

Answer (score 3):

Spring security also includes a class named [`SecurityContextHolder`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder.html). This class is a thread-safe "singleton" which allows you to access the login context for the current request. In particular, you can access the authentication principal by calling `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()`.

If you are using `LdapAuthenticationProvider` as an authentication provider, the default instance returned by calling `getPrincipal()` is going to be of type [`LdapUserDetailsImpl`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/ldap/userdetails/LdapUserDetailsImpl.html). This can be customized by implementing a custom [`UserDetailsContextMapper`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/ldap/userdetails/UserDetailsContextMapper.html) and injecting it into the `userDetailsContextMapper` property on your `LdapAuthenticationProvider` instance.

Comment: Thax Ryan, I went through your idea and did a spring security user login.that perfectly fine for me.

Comment: i add a user authentication query in spring security file.                                                       <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
 users-by-username-query="
        select username,password, enabled 
        from users where username=?" 
     authorities-by-username-query="
        select u.username, ur.authority from users u, user_roles ur 
        where u.user_id = ur.user_id and u.username =?  " 
        />                                                             but now i need to get the logged in user id from the user table

Comment: @Amila: Please accept the answer if it was what you were looking for. This helps to mark the question as "solved" and may thus benefit the community.

Answer (score 0):

An extract from :

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/technical-overview.html#d4e731

```
Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
  String username = ((UserDetails)principal).getUsername();
} else {
  String username = principal.toString();
}
```

Please visit the above link, it helped me alot. Good luck :)